# How to use Primefaces calendar in JSF page?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, calendar

I have a `h:panelGroup` in JSF page with input field for data selection:

```
<h:panelGroup>Date to change password</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:inputText value="#{AddAccountController.formMap['DATETOCHANGEPASSWD']}" autocomplete="off" >
        <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="35"/>
    </h:inputText>
</h:panelGroup>
```

The question is how I can integrate the [calendar](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/calendarTime.jsf) into the input menu. Something like this:

```
<h:panelGroup>Date to change password</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:inputText value="#{AddAccountController.formMap['DATETOCHANGEPASSWD']}" autocomplete="off" >
        <p:calendar value="#{AddAccountController.date4}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />  
        <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="35"/>
    </h:inputText>
</h:panelGroup>
```

I tested the code but it's not working. What is the proper way to use it into input field?

Comment: Can you explain your requirement in doing this? Do you want the calendar value be reflected in the inputText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

think you have to add two different field in from because this way it will not work in this way.

```
<h:panelGroup>Date to change password</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:inputText value="#{AddAccountController.formMap['DATETOCHANGEPASSWD']}" autocomplete="off" >
        <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="35"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <p:calendar value="#{AddAccountController.date4}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: I forgot to remove the old calendar. Your proposal is not working.